# HDRI Environment not showing on add - Blender 3.5

Tags: hdri

Issue: HDRI environment is not showing up when I add to project?

Machine - Mac Pro M1
Render setting - GPU Compute

I'm at the 2:55 mark in this tutorial and am stuck.
https://youtu.be/uUQ6GnMfKu8

Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your description is very vague, you need to add as much detail as you can about your setting and issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows you are in [solid shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#solid):

[image]

You should be in [Rendered Shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#rendered%7C).

[image]

It's the only one that shows an actual render of your scene in the viewport. The other shading modes only show some limited imitations of certain aspects of your scene, to provide you with different information during certain tasks that need it at a low resource cost.